# Copy rows of multiple workbooks into one main workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a workbook that contains only one sheet,
copy data up to column AC until last available row in column A,
paste the data into first empty row in column A in workbook "Mergedsheet.xlsx".

I want to loop over all workbooks present in a specific folder, but get lots of errors.

```
Sub MergeNew()
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim MergedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceData As Range
    Dim DestinationData As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileNames As String 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    FolderPath = "E:\Jan to March 2019\Bharuch 31\"
    FileNames = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While FileNames <> ""
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileNames)
        Range("A1:AC1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\Jan to March 2019\Bharuch 31\MergedSheet.xlsx"
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("A" & lastRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        'ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        FileNames = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through a folder and copy-pasting each workbook's first sheet's data to workbook A. However, workbook A is also in that folder. So you should take care to skip it (when looping).

(Alternatively, you could provide a different argument to the `DIR` function (e.g. some wildcard criteria that excludes workbook A if possible), so that you don't have to constantly check inside the loop.)

Untested.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MergeNew()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Uncomment this when you know code is working.
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Uncomment this when you know code is working.

    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = GetFolderPath(titleToShow:="Select the folder containing the files to loop through.")

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Dir$(folderPath & "*.xls*")

    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not find a relevant file in '" & folderPath & "'. Code will stop running now."
        Exit Sub ' No point in carrying on in such a case.
    End If

    Dim destinationFolderPath As String
    destinationFolderPath = GetFolderPath(titleToShow:="Select the folder to save the 'MergedSheet.xlsx' file to.")

    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add

    ' This line may throw an error
    destinationWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=destinationFolderPath & "MergedSheet.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = destinationWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' I assume there's only 1 sheet in there, but change as necessary.

    Do Until Len(Filename) = 0
        Dim fullFilePathToOpen As String
        fullFilePathToOpen = folderPath & Filename

        If fullFilePathToOpen <> destinationWorkbook.FullName Then ' Probably could have just compared filename since directory is the same, but this is more explicit
            Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
            Set sourceWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fullFilePathToOpen, ReadOnly:=True) ' If you don't make changes to the workbook you open, better to open as read-only

            Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
            Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' You say there's only one worksheet in there, so referring by index should be okay (for now)

            Dim lastSourceRow As Long
            lastSourceRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Assume last row can be determined from column A alone

            Dim lastDestinationRow As Long
            lastDestinationRow = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

            If destinationSheet.Rows.Count < (lastDestinationRow + lastSourceRow) Then
                MsgBox "Ran out of rows (in sheet '" & sourceSheet.Name & "' of workbook '" & destinationWorkbook.Name & "')"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            sourceSheet.Range("A1", sourceSheet.Cells(lastSourceRow, "AC")).Copy Destination:=destinationSheet.Cells(lastDestinationRow, "A")

            sourceWorkbook.Close False
        End If
        Filename = Dir$()
    Loop

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Uncomment this when you know code is working.
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Uncomment this when you know code is working.
End Sub

Private Function GetFolderPath(Optional ByVal titleToShow As String = vbNullString) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If Len(titleToShow) > 0 Then .Title = titleToShow
        .AllowMultiSelect = False ' Only one is allowed.
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Folder selection appears to have cancelled. Code will stop running now"
            End
        End If
        GetFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: .Cells Invalid or unqualified reference error. Please help.

Comment: @IRSMVad Sorry, try now.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Code is working but one I have to break the loop by pressing ESC after few moments as it seems infinite loop is running or excel not working. But after checking the desitination sheet all data are there as required. One thing Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1) =<Object variable or with block variable not set... and lastSourceRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row it shows error as sourceSheet.Rows.Count Automation error.

Comment: @IRSMVad, I think that's because I'd put the `Filename = Dir$()` inside the `IF` statement. It should be outside the `IF` statement (otherwise the loop can't advance once `Filename` is the name of `destinationWorkbook`). My bad, please try again.

Comment: Also, if this line `Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` is giving you trouble, can you change the `1` to the name of the worksheet (if it's the same for all the `sourceWorkbooks` that data is being copy-pasted from). I would change it, but I don't know the name of the worksheet.

Comment: now one problem.....The last row from each source sheet is unavailable in destination margedsheet. It starts pasting from source sheet to destination sheet from last copied pasted row. It has to do one increment in row to make all data available. I am totally novice in macro... But you have helped me a lot and provided brilliant solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @IRSMVad Change this line `lastDestinationRow = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` to `lastDestinationRow = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` (I'll change it in my code too)

Comment: Hi chillin... Can I get a dialogue box to 1) choose source folder 2)select a destination folder where it will create a workbook named MergedSheet having only one sheet? This will ease my work as for different locations I have to change codes every time.

Comment: @IRSMVad, I have added two dialogue boxes (one for source folder, the other for destination folder). If you have further questions, please ask a new question. If you think this question is solved, please mark it as so.